# Left-align org-mode like FoldingText... Regexp?

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions

I posted this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554179/left-align-org-mode-like-foldingtext) earlier, but perhaps this is a better place for it?

I am looking for a way to left-align text in Org-mode so that the paragraphs line up like in FoldingText. Here is an example:

```
  * Headline number 1
 ** Headline number 2 [0/2]

    Here is some text
    before our first unordered list:

  - List item 1
  - List item 2

    And here is a checklist:

  - [ ] Do this first
  - [ ] Do this next

 ** Headline number 4
```

I've tried using `align-regexp` but I am having trouble figuring the correct regex string... any ideas?

**Here's an update**

I got this working with the following code:

```
(defun align-ft (p1 p2)
  "Align outlines like FoldingText"
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp p1 p2 "\\(^\\*+\\s-\\|^-\\s-\\|^\\)." -1 0 nil)
)
```

The only problem is that it aligns text by adding spaces, and I don't want spaces hard-coded into the document. I just want it to display, as if the spaces were there (like in `org-indent-mode`). Also, this code requires the region to be highlighted and ultimately, I just want it to auto-align the entire document, as I type.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an xy problem.. may be you need to just enable `org-indent-mode`? Or are you aware of that, and that's not what you need? On top on that, may be `(setq org-hide-leading-stars t)`?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `org-indent-mode` now. But this gives me more of an outline view. What I would like to find is a way to shift all the markup characters (stars and hyphens) into the margin area, so that the text stays nicely aligned.

Comment: I don't think this exists. It will probably be non-trivial and will require rewriting the org indent functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this can be done with align-regexp. What I'm looking for is the regular expression to identify the delimiters.

Comment: The *alignment* could be done with `align-regexp`, but this will almost certainly break those parts of org that expect headlines stars (*) to start at the left margin, not at a variable number of spaces in from the margin. Given how fundamental headlines are, that's probably most of org mode.

Answer (score 0):

`org-indent-mode` adds the `line-prefix` and `wrap-prefix` special text properties. I'm not sure it's worth the hassle, but if you want to align your org buffer the desired way once, this may be for you:

```el
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (not (eobp))
    (let ((ind (make-string
                (- 4 (if (org-at-heading-p)
                         (org-current-level)
                       -1))
                ?\s)))
      (add-text-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)
                           `(line-prefix ,ind wrap-prefix ,ind)))
    (forward-line)))
```

Obviously you should deactivate `org-indent-mode` before.